# Linq select objects in Database exists Dictionary Keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dictionary

I want to query data from database by multiple primary keys at once by using Linq. However, I store my primary keys in `Dictionary<int, string>`

**My dictionary**

```
private Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1, "Value 1"},
    {2, "Value 2"},
    {3, "Value 3"},
    {4, "Value 4"},
    {5, "Value 5"},
    {6, "Value 6"}

 };
```

**In Raw SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM Article WHERE ArticleId IN (1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

**I have tried in Linq**

```
var article = new NewsEntities().Articles;
var mainArticles = article.Where(a => dict.ContainsKey(a.ArticleId));

foreach (var mainArticle in mainArticles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mainArticle.ArticleId);
}
```

**The error I have got**

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method 'Boolean ContainsKey(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Try add `AsEnumerable`: `article.AsEnumerable().Where(a => dict.ContainsKey(a.ArticleId));`.

Comment: Tetsuya Yamamoto It gives me a single incorrect result.

Comment: What incorrect result you have then? And what values you want to display using `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: I want to get Article objects, but it gives me only one row.

Comment: Just use `ToList`: `article.ToList().Where(a => dict.Contains(a.ArticleId));`. No need to use `ContainsKey` there.

Comment: Eric method works very well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq to Entities does not support dictionary methods, use `List` instead

```
var article = new NewsEntities().Articles;
var list = new List<int>(dict.Keys);
var mainArticles = article.Where(a => list.Contains(a.ArticleId));
```